# In my project i am getting an different type of error when i am running listed code using Keras Library in different Systems

Tags: python-3.x, keras

This problem is not arising when i am using Colab.
When i am running fit statement following problem arises in different 
system
1.In colab there is no error but this is too much slow as it is just a 
part of my project
2.In Nvidia Titanx 12 Gb GPU i am getting an Resource Exhaust error
3.In a 33Gb GPU workstation i am getting a different error i am attaching 
the error statements with this problem. Also only this code is showing problem in this system.

```
input_sh=Input(shape=(256,256,1))
x=Conv2D(128,(3,3),strides=1,activation='relu',padding='same')(input_sh)
x=Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
x=Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',strides=1,padding='same')(x)
mapp=Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
x=MaxPooling2D((2,2))(mapp)

x=Conv2D(10,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same',name='sal')(x)
encod=MaxPooling2D((2,2),name='ecod')(x)
x=UpSampling2D((2,2))(encod)
x=Conv2D(10,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
x=UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
x=Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',strides=1,padding='same')(x)
x=UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
x=Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',strides=1,padding='same')(x)
x=Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation='relu',strides=1,padding='same')(x)
x=Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation='relu',strides=1,padding='same')(x)
x=Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation='relu',strides=1,padding='same')(x)
x=Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation='relu',strides=2,padding='same')(x)
decod=Conv2D(1,(3,3),activation='sigmoid',padding='same')(x)
saliency=Model(input_sh,decod)
saliency.summary()
from skimage.color import rgb2lab, lab2rgb, rgb2gray
folder=r"F:\INTERN\Subset16k"
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if 
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, f))]
xdataset=np.ndarray(shape=(800,256,256,1),dtype=np.float32)
ydataset=np.ndarray(shape=(800,256,256,2),dtype=np.float32)
vxdataset=np.ndarray(shape=(200,256,256,1),dtype=np.float32)
vydataset=np.ndarray(shape=(200,256,256,2),dtype=np.float32)
xtestset=np.ndarray(shape=(50,256,256,1),dtype=np.float32)
ytestset=np.ndarray(shape=(50,256,256,2),dtype=np.float32)

for i in range(0,1050):
if(i==1):
print('pass')
ft=folder + "/" + onlyfiles[i]
im=load_img(ft)
x=img_to_array(im)

lab_image = rgb2lab(1.0/255*x)
x= (lab_image + [0, 128, 128]) / [100, 255, 255] 
if(i<800):
xdataset[i]=x[:,:,0].reshape(256,256,1)
ydataset[i]=x[:,:,1:]
elif(i<1000):
vxdataset[i-800]=x[:,:,0].reshape(256,256,1)
vydataset[i-800]=x[:,:,1:]
else:
xtestset[i-1000]=x[:,:,0].reshape(256,256,1)
ytestset[i-1000]=x[:,:,1:]
saliency.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')
saliency.fit(xdataset,xdataset,epochs=10,verbose=1)
```

---

```
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-16-a5e8d074b015> in <module>
----> 1 saliency.fit(tx,tx,epochs=5,verbose=1)

~\Anaconda3\envs\Suvidha\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in 
fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, 
validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, 
steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
1037                                         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
1038                                         
steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1039                                         
validation_steps=validation_steps)
1040 
1041     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

~\Anaconda3\envs\Suvidha\lib\site- 
packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, f, ins, 
out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, 
shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, 
validation_steps)
197                     ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
198 
--> 199                 outs = f(ins_batch)
200                 outs = to_list(outs)
201                 for l, o in zip(out_labels, outs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\Suvidha\lib\site- 
packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)
2716         else:
2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\Suvidha\lib\site- 
packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
2673             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, 
run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
2674         else:
-> 2675             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
2676         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
2677 

~\Anaconda3\envs\Suvidha\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, 
**kwargs)
1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
1440         if run_metadata:
1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~\Anaconda3\envs\Suvidha\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, 
type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
526             None, None,
527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it 
stays alive
530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback 
due to
UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably 
because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning 
log message was printed above.
[[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
[[{{node loss/mul}}]]
```

Comment: It looks like a CUDA problem. Are you using a container from https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/gpu-cloud/containers/?

Comment: No I am not using cloud. I have a dedicated physical workstation where I am running this code.

Comment: You can (and, in my opinion, should) still use the NGC docker container. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: I dont understand, why this simple code with 800 training images of size 256*256 is giving me resouce exhauseted error, only for this code...Although to check, I have executed another code having 4000 images of same size. My system configuration is Titanx Ge Force(16GB RAM, 11 GB Graphics).And the code is running in Google Colab, but taking very long time...Pls help me out for this problem

Comment: I don't know anything about Google Colab. Sorry.